# Перебор файлов в каталоге JavaScript

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Имеется папка с картинками, пути к ним вручную вносятся в массив и затем используются. Есть ли вариант заполнить массив изображениями средствами JS (чтобы не нужно было при изменении количества изображений руками менять содержимое массива)????

Заниматься данным делом нужно на клиенте.

Comment: откуда у клиента доступ к файловой системе? только через посредника в виде некоего скрипта на бэкэнде.

Comment: _некоего скрипта на бэкэнде_ который и будет выполнять то, что написано в условии. А так на клиенте это сделать не возможно.